# How to Convert Date values in SAS into Regular Dates Using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, date, ssis, sas

I was pulling some data from SAS server and i have encountered some issues with the way SAS stores their date values, it is like numerical values.  I am getting some wrong date value when i finish importing the data from SAS into SQL server.  SAS date values is a value that represents the number of days between January 1, 1960, and a specified date.  so all what i want is to convert the SAS date value into mm/dd/yyyy format.  I am using SSIS package to pull the data. Here is an example of how SAS stores their date values.  thanks
[image]

Comment: The Jan 2002 date value is hilariously wrong. It's a bit over 15000 not 88000.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used SSIS, but in TSQL I know you can do `select DATEADD(day,N,'19600101')`.  N is the number held by SAS.

```
select DATEADD(day,35,'19600101')
```

Returns:

```
1960-02-05 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: thank you so much.  can you tell me what is this number 19600101?

Comment: 1/1/1960.  You could do '1960-01-01'